# iOS Memory App Closure

Tags: ios, swift

When putting my app in the background, then running a bunch of other apps one after the other, it will eventually close my app due to phone memory management. This is understandable. My question is, can anything be done to notify the user A) The app closed because of memory and needs to be booted back up. OR B) Have some sort memory watcher to when the phone memory is getting low to alert the user?

Are either of these possible? Are any other options available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is understandable

Understandable but not necessary in the short term. You cannot prevent your app from eventually being terminated, but you should be doing everything you can to keep it off the "short list" of apps to be terminated when memory is needed, by shedding memory usage as you go into the background.

> can anything be done to notify the user A) The app closed because of memory and needs to be booted back up

No. You cannot "notify the user" when your app has been backgrounded and suspended, because it has been suspended — it isn't *running*. You can't *do* anything at all. No code is actually being executed. You are like a frozen corpse. Unlike the corpse, you can be revived and brought back to life, but that is entirely up the user, who must summon you to the front again.

Your job in this respect is to make it, as much as possible, *not matter* whether or not the app was terminated while in suspension. If you were not terminated, you'll be revived in exactly the state you were in when you went into the background. Well, then see to it that if you are launched from scratch because you were terminated, you *also* return to the state you were in when you went into the background.